# Degenerate operators - block diagonal matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

It is known that if we have two operators $\hat{A},\hat{B}$  such that $[A,B]=0$ and they are both not degenerate (each eigenvalues has only one eigenvector) then they can be simultaneously diagonalized with the same basis. What I don't understand is the case that $\hat{A}$ for example is degenerate, I see everywhere that in that case $\hat{B}$ is a block diagonal matrix.
The math indeed shows that in that case, $$\left\langle u_{i}^{m}\left|\hat{B}\right|u_{i}^{n}\right\rangle $$ where the $u_i$ are the eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue, is no longer promised to behave as Kronecker's Delta. Why does it mean it $\hat{B}$ will surely be represented by a block diagonal matrix, having zeros everywhere outside degenerate blocks? I tried to work it out from the math with no successes, since it is far from being trivial for me.

Comment: "I see everywhere that in that case B^ is a block diagonal matrix." can you mention the source also?

Comment: For instance: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/study-materials/MIT8_04S13_OnCommEigenbas.pdf on page 4.

Answer (score 1):

> If two observables are compatible (i.e. $[A,B]=0$), their corresponding operators
> **possess a set of common (or simultaneous) eigenstates** (this theorem
> holds for both degenerate and nondegenerate eigenstates). (This is theorem 3.1 from N. Zettili.)

If **both are nondegenerate** we can go **further** and say that all possible sets of eigen states of one operator also are eigen states for the other.

But in the degenerate case (lets say A is degenerate but not B) we **possibly can** also find a set of eigenstates of A which may not be eigen states of B. One way to construct these is we can first find the eigen states of B and then all of them will be eigen states of A. Now we can take those eigen states for which eigen value for A is same and form their linear combinations. Now we can replace the old eigenstates of B with the linear combinations. Now this new set of states are eigen states of A but not B.

Even if two operators are not compatible (i.e. $[A,B]\neq 0$) **it still is possible** to have an common eigen state because $[A,B]\psi =0$ might still hold true for some $\psi$. To say that two operators do not have common eigen states we need a stronger condition that $[A,B]\psi \neq 0$ $\forall \psi$.

**Edit:** In the case where $[A,B]=0$ and both are degenerate, if both observables **are degenerate at the exact same eigen values and the number of independent states which that eigen value is also same**(i.e. dimensionality of degeneracy), then also we can say that nd say that all possible sets of eigen states of one operator also are eigen states for the other. **If they are degenerate at different eigen values** then it is **possible** to have a set of eigenstates of A which may not be eigen states of B.

Comment: @QLmrt I added it. But it can be easily understood from the above 2 cases.

Comment: I added another answer to explain how to build a common eigenbasis in the fully degenerate case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complement to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632563).

In the case where both $A$ and $B$ are degenerate, we can still find a common eigenbasis. To do this, we use the spectral theorem to diagonalize $A$ in an orthonormal basis $\{ |a,n \rangle\}$ (with $a$ the eigenvalue and $n$ to index the degenerate eigenvectors). The eigenspace $E_a$ of $A$ is the vector space spanned by the $|a,n\rangle$ for all possible $n$. It is the space of all eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$.

If we take an arbitrary $|\psi \rangle \in E_a$, we see that $AB|\psi\rangle = B A|\psi\rangle  = a B|\psi\rangle$, so that $B|\psi\rangle \in E_a$.

We can therefore apply the spectral theorem to $B$ on the space $E_a$, to find a orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $B$. Since all vectors in $E_a$ are already eigenvectors of $A$, the new ones are common eigenvectors.

Now we put together all the vectors we obtained for the different values of $a$, and we get a basis for the whole Hilbert space, composed of eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$.